# Get value when ID is changing

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to retrieve value "[wkSu-'$bS[U#;" from HTML bellow. The issue is that id="ext-comp-1328" and id="ext-gen1578" are always changing. My code so far to get to a specific page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys       
import time    

my_login="SuperMegaUser"
my_pin="960790"+input()

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(r'https://cyberark.supermegacorp.com/PasswordVault/logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPasswordVault%2fdefault.aspx')
assert "Password Vault Sign In" in driver.title
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_txtUsername"]').send_keys(my_login)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_txtPassword"]').send_keys(my_pin)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="pvBody_PageTemplate_innerHolder_ctrlLogon_btnLogon"]').click()
time.sleep(10)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="ext-gen159"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[19]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="ext-gen159"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[17]/div').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="reason"]').send_keys("0")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="reason"]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="password-windows-fieldset-body password-windows-fieldset-body-noheader" id="ext-gen1578"><label id="ext-comp-1327" class=" account-password-display password-labels">[wkSu-'$bS[U#;</label><table id="ext-comp-1328" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn password-window-copy-btn password-labels x-btn-noicon" style="width: auto;"><tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left"><tr><td class="x-btn-tl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-tc"></td><td class="x-btn-tr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button type="button" id="ext-gen1593" class=" x-btn-text">Copy</button></em></td><td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-bl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-bc"></td><td class="x-btn-br"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: My guess is that if you used a CSS selector, e.g. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label.account-password-display").text`, that you would get the text you want.

Comment: @JeffC Thank I'll let you know if it works. Though I'm unfamiliar with css I'd like to point out the class name is: " account-password-display password-labels"

Comment: That's actually two class names. My guess is that you don't need both. If you shared the page URL, I could look and tell you for sure.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've added it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML you provided, the line below should get you what you want.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label.account-password-display").text
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch text use `text` instead of `click()` only `text` no parenthesis

For **ext-**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[contains(@id,"ext-gen")]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[17]/div').click()

OR

driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[matches(@id,"^.*?ext-gen.*$")]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[17]/div').click()

OR


driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[matches(@id,"ext-gen")]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[17]/div').click()
```

For **ext-comp-**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[contains(@id,"ext-comp-")]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[17]/div').click()

OR


driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[matches(@id,"^.*?ext-comp-.*$")]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[17]/div').click()

OR


driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[matches(@id,"ext-comp-")]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[17]/div').click()
```

I found one more that is [starts-with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[starts-with(@id,"ext-gen")]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[17]/div').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[starts-with(@id,"ext-comp-")]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[17]/div').click()
```

Comment: Thanks your examples are helpful. Though I stated to retrieve a value, not to click on it.

Comment: Thanks. yes, that's why I mentioned `.text` need to use instead of `click`. Yes of-course @JeffC's answer is short and awesome, as you have class selector may be more robust solution.